# Access UIElement in a TreeViewItem that has been modified by a HierachicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

my Silverlight 4 application contains a treeview. I have customized the look of the TreeViewItems with an HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<sdk:TreeView x:Name="TreeViewModel" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateTreeViewDisplayObjects}" .../>

<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTreeViewDisplayObjects" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
  <Grid>
    <Border x:Name="BorderComponent" .../>
  </Grid>
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Eventually, I need to parse through all TreeViewItems and access an UIElement (i.e. the "BorderComponent"). Like so:

```
foreach (TreeViewItem tvi in _myTreeView.Items)
  tvi.BorderComponent.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because Items will return the bound object. And even if I could access the TreeViewItem (_myTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem to get the first one), I don't know how to access the Border, because the TreeViewItem doesn't know about the HierarchicalDataTemplate, that is used to create the items.

Any idea, how I could access the "BorderComponent"-item in each TreeViewItem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid directly accessing UI-components, you can just bind the `Visibility` to a property on your item and set that to `Collapsed`.

To actually access the `Border` you probably can do so as well, the data template which creates it should be found in something like a `HeaderTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem`, i haven't used the Toolkit though so i cannot tell you for certain. Using `FindName` on the template you might be able to get the `Border` then.